# Apache Nifi read flowfile content

Tags: apache-nifi, flowfile

I would like to access the content of a flow file that should contain binary data but when I execute this code:

```
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {

       FlowFile ff = session.get(); 
       Logger.info("Flowfile size : " + ff.getSize());

       session.read(ff, new InputStreamCallback() {
       @Override
       public void process(InputStream in) throws IOException {
          Logger.info("InputStream size : " + in.available());
          …
       }
    }
}
```

I have this:

```
Flowfile size : 46662
InputStream size : 0
```

As a result, I don’t have any data to read.

Can someone guide me on how to read correctly the flow file content?

Comment: use `stream.read()` or `stream.read(byte[])`

Comment: I cannot find stream.read or stream.read(byte[]), so I’m using StreamUtils